# Load byte array as a class in Java system packages

Tags: java, classloader

Anyone has idea how to class load a dynamically generated bytecode, which is expected to be in Java system class package (the package name starts with java.lang....).

```
public class ByteCodeClassLoader extends ClassLoader{
    public static Class<?> run(String className, byte[] b){
         ....
         return load(className, b);
    }
    public   Class<?> load(String className,  byte[] b){
            .............
            Class<?> expClass = null;
            synchronized(this){
                expClass =defineClass(className, b, 0, b.length);
            }
            return expClass;

        return null;
    }
```

When I try to run the code (the `className` is java/lang/invoke/DYNGuardWithTestHandle0), it throws exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/invoke/DYNGuardWithTestHandle0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:346)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.lang.invoke.ByteCodeClassLoader.load(ByteCodeClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.invoke.ByteCodeClassLoader.run(ByteCodeClassLoader.java:54)
```

Thanks.

---

The given name is java/lang/invoke/DYNGuardWithTestHandle0, while the class name in the byte[] stream is java.lang.invoke.DYNGuardWithTestHandle0. After making both consistent, the class loading would still fail because the package `java.lang`is protected package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javadoc of [`defineClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String,%20byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain)) says:

> Throws `NoClassDefFoundError` if `name` is not equal to the binary name of the class specified by [byte array]